# Cannot install 64-bit iTunes (v10.5) on Vista

Tags: itunes, software-update, windows

I've tried upgrading iTunes, un-installing and reinstalling. Removing all Apple software from my machine. Running the installer with administrative rights. Installing Quicktime independently of iTunes. I've searched everywhere I can about this error I'm experiencing and I still haven't resolved the issue. I've even been through [Apple's support article.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1926)

Acording to the statistics found under my *System* in the *Control Panel*, I am in fact running on a 64-bit OS. Below is the error I'm faced with during installation. Clicking *OK* cancels the installation wizard.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did some digging because I knew I have seen this error before. It looks like it is not a direct issue with iTunes but with your Microsoft Virtual C++ redistributable. I resolved it by following the steps in http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/microsoftvc80crtversion80507274053typewin32publick/c1359ee5-e18d-4512-8bff-890936db2810

You are clearly not the only one having this issue, and the steps can be generalized to:

1. Run windows update
2. Download and update your Microsoft C++ redistributable http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=766a6af7-ec73-40ff-b072-9112bab119c2&displaylang=en#filelist

That has worked for me for a couple of different people's problems, and I hope it fixes yours.

There are additional steps in the thread such as some registry fixes for the windows installer service, however I would give these steps a try first, especially since they cant really cause any harm.

Comment: I had one update for Vista 64-bit. Unfortunatly it disappeared and 'Windows could not search for new updates' Now I've got a non-apple related problem... Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You should reinstall all your Microsoft C++ redistributable packages and install all of them (x86 and x64): for VC 2005, 2008, 2010. and then install iTunes 10.5